# Bottleneck for Numpy-based Recursive Function to Undo Max Pooling

Tags: python, numpy, recursion

I've devised a recursive function to handle a specific problem within the deep learning community. It seems to work quickly and well for most cases, but then takes ~20 minutes for other cases for seemingly no reason. The function, in the simplest case, can be abstracted as simply numpy's "repeat" function on two axes. Here's the code I used to test this function:

```
def recursive_upsample(fMap, index, dims):
    if index == 0:
        return fMap
    else:
        start = time.time()
        upscale = np.zeros((dims[index-1][0],dims[index-1][1],fMap.shape[-1]))
        if dims[index-1][0] % 2 == 1 and dims[index-1][1] % 2 == 1:
            crop = fMap[:fMap.shape[0]-1,:fMap.shape[1]-1]
            consX = fMap[-1,:][:-1]
            consY = fMap[:,-1][:-1]
            corner = fMap[-1,-1]
            crop = crop.repeat(2, axis=0).repeat(2, axis=1)
            upscale[:crop.shape[0],:crop.shape[1]] = crop
            upscale[-1,:][:-1] = consX.repeat(2,axis=0)
            upscale[:,-1][:-1] = consY.repeat(2,axis=0)
            upscale[-1,-1] = corner

        elif dims[index-1][0] % 2 == 1:
            crop = fMap[:fMap.shape[0]-1]
            consX = fMap[-1:,]
            crop = crop.repeat(2, axis=0).repeat(2, axis=1)
            upscale[:crop.shape[0]] = crop
            upscale[-1:,] = consX.repeat(2,axis=1)

        elif dims[index-1][1] % 2 == 1:
            crop = fMap[:,:fMap.shape[1]-1]
            consY = fMap[:,-1]
            crop = crop.repeat(2, axis=0).repeat(2, axis=1)
            upscale[:,:crop.shape[1]] = crop
            upscale[:,-1] = consY.repeat(2,axis=0)


        else:
            upscale = fMap.repeat(2, axis=0).repeat(2, axis=1)

        print('Upscaling from {} to {} took {} seconds'.format(fMap.shape,upscale.shape,time.time() - start))
        fMap = upscale

        return recursive_upsample(fMap,index-1,dims)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dims = [(634,1020,64),(317,510,128),(159,255,256),(80,128,512),(40,64,512)]
    images = []
    for dim in dims:
        image = np.random.rand(dim[0],dim[1],dim[2])
        images.append(image)
    start = time.time()
    upsampled = []
    for index,image in enumerate(images):
        upsampled.append(recursive_upsample(image,index,dims))
    print('Upsampling took {} seconds'.format(time.time() - start))
```

For some odd reason, the point in the recursion where the feature map of shape (40,64,512) is being upsampled from shape (317,510,512) to (634,1020,512) takes an egregious 941 seconds! I'm starting to rewrite this code with Theano, but should I be looking to some underlying problem with my code? My reasoning as of right now is that computing this on CPU is unwieldy, but I'm not sure what the hold up is with such a simple function. Also any tips on how to make this function faster would be appreciated!

Comment: Aside: it seems that when manually going through the code for upscaling the (317,510,512) image to (634,1020,512) in the interpreter, you run into a MemoryError. This problem seems possibly intractable.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to do the recursion. E.g. for the `(40,64,512)` image you can directly do:

```
upsampled = image.repeat(16, axis=0).repeat(16, axis=1)[:634,:1020]
```